Format(Color) Specific Text in sheet using G-App Script
In Sheet1 I have a Data like below

Sales count Increased to +12% in current Year
Sales Count Decreased to -12% in current Qtr
Florida Sales went Up Hawaii went Down

I want to change the color of Specific text in the Data existing in the Sheet1.
The specific texts which I want to change the color are declared as array in my code. Array name is pos_text
I am using the following solution from @doubleunary
And here is the code:
function changecolor() {  
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                            .getSheetByName("Sheet13").getRange("D2:H8");
  var c_values = range.getValues();
  var bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
  var count = 0;
  var pos_text =['Increased','up','high','more','positive'];      
  var colors;
  var srch_text='Increased';
  Logger.log(pos_text.length);
   
  for(i=0;i<pos_text.length;i++){
    const regex = new RegExp(pos_text[i].replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'),'gi');
    const num_regex = new RegExp('[-]?[0-9]\&*','gi');        
    const format = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor('#55883B').build();
    const values = range.getDisplayValues();
    Logger.log(values);
    
    if(values!=null){
      let match;
      const formattedText = values.map(row => row.map(value => {    
      const richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(value);
      while (match = regex.exec(value)) {
        Logger.log("While " + match);    
        richText.setTextStyle(match.index, match.index + match[0].length, format);
      }
      while (match = num_regex.exec(value)) {
        richText.setTextStyle(match.index, match.index + match[0].length, format);
      } 
      return richText.build();
    }));
      range.setRichTextValues(formattedText); 
  }
}
}

As per the solution given in this Bold specific text in Google Sheets
Single text is passed, Instead I want to pass the Array List. To do so I tried the above code I pasted, the code I modified only changes the numbers not texts. Not sure where I am missing.

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Thanks for correcting, I have made an edit. Hope its clear now.

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If my understanding of your expected result was not correct, I apologize.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result when your showing script is modified, how about modifying it as follows?
Modified script:
Please set your range to rangeA1Notation as A1Notation.
function formatPhraseInText() {
  const rangeA1Notation = "'Sheet13'!D2:H8";
  const pos_text = ['Increased', 'up', 'high', 'more', 'positive'];

  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  const format = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor('#55883B').build();
  const values = range.getDisplayValues();
  let match;
  const formattedText = values.map(row => row.map(value => {
    const richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(value);
    pos_text.forEach(t => {
      const regex = new RegExp(t.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'), 'gi');
      while (match = regex.exec(value)) {
        richText.setTextStyle(match.index, match.index + match[0].length, format);
      }
    });
    return richText.build();
  }));
  range.setRichTextValues(formattedText);
}

Testing:
When this script is run, the following result is obtained.
From:

To:


Will check and Accept as Answer ASAP. Again Thank you!!
